# Question about earthquake data attribute codes

Tags: earthquakes, database

I have some earthquake data with an attribute field call M and has values c, h , l , m or w.

There is another one called Magnitude so I assume its not that.

Any ideas what M represents and what the codes mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show maybe a small sample of that data? Maybe the range of values would help.

Comment: This could be "Magnitude Type" where c = coda, h = helicorder, l = local, w = moment.  Though I am thrown off that m is one of the choices.

Comment: @farrenthorpe I think you're right - have a look at http://www.ncedc.org/db/Documents/NewSchemas/PI/v1.6.0/PI.1.6.0/Content/Tbl_388b53c4f81611d6bcce00c04f794c81_Attr.htm and scroll down to `magtype` - you could probably get an answer out of it.

Comment: @SabreTooth that one doesn't have an 'm' option either.  I think without knowing the source of the data it's tough to say what that 'm' stands for ... I haven't found any magnitude type examples that include 'm' as one of the options.

Comment: @farrenthorpe same here, I am half suspecting that the statement in the question is literally 'm or w'  But, you're right, we need the source.